# Consuming a ASMX Service from a ASP.NET MVC 3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asmx

As the title suggests I am trying to consume a ASMX service from a MVC 3 application. My problem is that I keep getting an error telling there is no service at that location. However, there is.
Here is my AJAX service call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/UI.Web/services/ProgramCycles.asmx/SaveProgramCycles",
            data: "{'pc_json':'" + JSON.stringify(cycles) + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

            }
```

The service exists in a folder within the root of my MVC 3 application but the call still errors that it can't find it.
Here is my service method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string SaveProgramCycles(string pc_json)
    {
        List<ProgramCycle> intakeBenefits = JSONHelper<ProgramCycle>.DeserializeListFromJsonToList(pc_json);

        return "It worked!";
    }
```

Comment: Have you built the service? Is this a web site, or a web application project?

Comment: Also, if it's a SOAP service, then it wants the JSON wrapped in a SOAP envelope.

Comment: It's a  MVC 3 web application project.